# accessing a c++ unique pointer declared in hpp file when set in a cpp file through constructor

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm a c++ beginner and am a little confused about how I would set a private unique from a class constructor while still managing to access it from other public functions. Should I even be using a unique pointer to begin with or a shared pointer instead?

**example:** (from a project I was working on)

header.hpp

```
class PixelHandler {
private:
// don't know if this ia legal
 std::unique_ptr<Ppm> ppm;
 std::vector<std::vector<int>> coordList;
 std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> generatePassList(std::unordered_map<int, int>);
 

public:
 PixelHandler(int sizex, int sizey);
 PixelHandler(std::string picture);
 std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> retrievePasswordList();
 void setPasswordList(std::string key, std::string password);

};
```

source.cpp

```
PixelHandler::PixelHandler(std::string picture)
{
  
   ppm = Ppm(picture.substr(0, -4) + ".ppm");

}
```

Comment: Since it's a `unique_ptr` you need to construct an object it can actually manage, e.g.: via `std::make_unique`. Other than that I don't understand what the question is, you have a private member, what do you mean by "access it from other public functions"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should do:

```
ppm = std::make_unique<Ppm>(picture.substr(0, -4) + ".ppm");
```

Because you can't assign the object (of type `Ppm`) to a pointer. You need to pass it to the constructor of the `std::unique_ptr` so that it can create a unique pointer that is pointing to that object.

Comment: Or preferably: `PixelHandler::PixelHandler(std::string picture) : ppm(std::make_unique<Ppm>(picture.substr(0, -4) + ".ppm")) {}`

Answer (score 1):

> Should I even be using a unique pointer to begin with or a shared
> pointer instead?

You can't be advised about that without knowing the use that you will give to the pointer. Will `PixelHandler` be the only class accessing `ppm`? Even if you access it from different points within `PixelHandler`, how will those other accesses be? For example, would it be enough for other accessors to receive a raw pointer to `ppm` (e.g. read-only operations over `Ppm`)?... The decision between using a `unique_ptr` or a `shared_ptr` has mainly to do with ownership over the object you point to.

> I'm a c++ beginner and am a little confused about how I would set a
> private unique from a class constructor while still managing to access
> it from other public functions.

You can initialize the `Ppm` pointer at `PixelHandler`'s constructor, then use it from the other `PixelHandler`'s methods. The `Ppm` instance won't be destroyed until the `PixelHandler` instance is destroyed.

BTW, if you want to form a `Ppm` path from a picture path (e.g. a `jpg`, `png` and so on), you can use the facilities from the `std::filesystem` (`path` and `replace_extension`). I don't think that `substr(0, -4)` works in C++ as a way to remove an extension.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4v93hP79)

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <memory>  // make_unique, unique_ptr
#include <string>

class Ppm
{
    const std::string file_extension{"ppm"};
public:
    Ppm(std::filesystem::path path)
    : path_{path.replace_extension(file_extension)}
    {
        
        std::cout << "Ppm ctor: " << path_ << "\n";
    }
    ~Ppm() { std::cout << "Ppm dtor\n"; }
private:
    std::filesystem::path path_{};
};

class PixelHandler
{
public:
    PixelHandler(std::filesystem::path path)
    : ppm_up_{std::make_unique<Ppm>(std::move(path))}
    {}
    ~PixelHandler() { std::cout << "PixelHandler dtor\n"; }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Ppm> ppm_up_{};
};

int main()
{
    PixelHandler ph("blah.jpg");
    std::cout << "\n... short life :(\n\n";
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks! I first had written `path_{std::move(file_path.replace_extension(file_extension))}` but then I thought it would not be a good idea to modify something and then move it.

Comment: Many thanks! :) You needn't have  to remove your comments. They were quite educative, especially the last one.

Comment: Oups... I've already forgotten what I wrote in that but I think your answer speaks for itself, so I removed my ramblings. :)